# (recent) Python Wrapper for Twitter API

Tags: python, twitter, python-twitter

I'm looking for a python wrapper for current Twitter API just to perform simple searches, but the wrappers I've tried (twython, python-twitter, etc.) are all outdated, and cannot perform search with under current Twitter.

Is there a python wrapper that is updated to work with current twitter?

Answer (score 0):

If you need only searches — take one of the python's OAuth libs ([this one](https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2) for example), and make calls yourself. For small subset of requests it would be faster solution then searching and evaluating different libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I used
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-twitter/
about a year or two ago and it's still in the same version 0.8.2. It served well for all I needed at that point - just posting tweets. If you're about to do something simple, it may suffice.

Answer (score 0):

I figured, to perform a simple search,
it's better not to go through all the wrappers...
You can simply use http GET search as follows:

```
import urllib2
parent = urllib2.urlopen("https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/show.json?id=291095878196920320&include_entities=true").read()
```

you can of course write it to file, etc.